# RequiredFieldValidation on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i got a little problem with the RequiredFieldValidation on asp.net. what i want to happen is when i click the "Log out" button the required field errors wont show up. i just want to know how to control this little beasts. that when i only press "Submit" button that is the only time they would check on errors, and when i press "Logout" button they would just sit there and wont show up.

[image]

[image: they show up when i hit the logout button]

Answer (score 2):

try this

You need to stop the validation with the help of attribute **CausesValidation="false"**

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnLogOut" runat="server" Text="Logout" CausesValidation="false" />
```

**CausesValidation**

1. When its true, it will fire the validation
2. when its false it will stop the validation

Comment: I would also suggest wrapping the validations if not already in a validation group.

Comment: its pleasure to help ... :)

Comment: @FlorianSchaal thanks for the idea im going to study on how to use that. thanks again sir.